# Pseudo code to C++ code

Tags: c++

I need some help to convert this pseudo code to c++ code

```
RandomizeArray(String: array[])
    Integer: max_i = *Upper bound of array*
    For i = 0 To max_i - 1
    // Pick the item for position i in the array.
    Integer: j = *pseudorandom number between i and max_i inclusive*
    *Swap the values of array[i] and array[j]*
    Next i  
End RandomizeArray
```

I tried this code but it seems I did something wrong. or is it correct?

```
char RandomizeArray[];
int max_i = 10;
for(int i=0; i < max_i; i++)
{
     char temp;
     temp = RandomizeArray[i];
     int j = rand() % max_i + i;
     RandomizeArray[i] = RandomizeArray[j];
     RandomizeArray[j] = temp;
}
```

I think it might be correct but I don't understand the part where he wants me to "Pick the item for position i in the array."

Comment: Start out by understanding what the pseudo code is trying to say. The first part you can pretty much assume is a function name as it has the signature of a function, meaning it's a label followed by an argument list and the End statement at the bottom kind of gives it away.

Comment: Here's the C++ code: `std::random_shuffle(RandomArray, RandomArray + max_i);`

Comment: So should I change "**int j = rand() % max_i + i;**" to std::random_shuffle(RandomArray, RandomArray + max_i);

Comment: @TayfurGazioglu No, change the whole thing you posted to `std::random_shuffle`.  It already does everything your code is attempting to do, only correctly (and there are now even better functions than `random_shuffle`, but I leave that as an exercise).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The thing is I need to learn the logic behind converting pseudo code to any language. Also this was a quiz question I did this code but I believe this code is not correct.

Comment: @TayfurGazioglu Please post what you found out to be not correct.  Also, the implementation of `random_shuffle` is similar to the psuedo-code (but not totally the same).   http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can this be done better using standard library functions? Hell yes.
At the very least,

```
temp = RandomizeArray[i];
RandomizeArray[i] = RandomizeArray[j];
RandomizeArray[j] = temp;
```

Is all replaced by

```
std::swap(RandomizeArray[i], RandomizeArray[j]);
```

The whole process is sort-of replaced (but not quite. Almost certainly a different backing algorithm) by the [std::random_shuffle family](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle), but that would be totally defeating the point of the exercise.

Unless the examiner is the sort to go, "Oh! He recognized the algorithm and suggested a time saving replacement! Excellent! Excellent!" Look for these sorts of bosses. They are generally more fun to work for.

Anyway... Is The OP's solution a correct interpretation of the Pseudo Code?

No.

Take a look at `int j = rand() % max_i + i;` and run though the possible range of values for j as you proceed through the values of i.

```
i = 0 : [0 .. max_i] 
i = 1 : [1 .. max_i + 1]
i = 2 : [2 .. max_i + 2]
```

Note the upper bound is moving, violating the contract of the Pseudo Code. As of i = 1, j may be outside the range of RandomizeArray and it will only get more likely from there on up.

Using a slight modification, `int j = rand() % (max_i - i) + i;`

```
i = 0 : [0 .. max_i] 
i = 1 : [1 .. max_i]
i = 2 : [2 .. max_i]
```

Extra note: `rand` sucks. [C++11 and better have a number of fun toys for generating much better random numbers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random). A [uniform_int_distribution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) is probably what you'd want here.

Comment: Thank you dude u're awesome. :)